# making a project with JIRA rest API. getting an Error as a response. But don't know the solution

Tags: post, jira, jira-rest-api

I am running Jira on docker. And making a simple rest API call to make a new project.
But I am getting an error "You must specify a valid project lead".
I AM indeed specifying a valid user called "**userOne**" that I have made on my server.
***Can someone help me out what the problem is?***
I have attached a picture of the POST request that I am making
and the response that I am getting. [image]

Additionally: the user that I am trying to make as a the lead is an ACTIVE user,
The screeenshot for that is attached below too.[in case that is something that can cause problems]
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

userOne is the full name of your user. The endpoint is expecting the username (which is unique across the whole instance), try changing it to user1.